# What the Japanese onomatopoeia for crunch?

Tags: word-requests, onomatopoeia

As in chewing or crunching on something, specifically when something is chewing loudly or roughly, like an animal eating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It partially depends on what is eaten.

- [くちゃくちゃ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83/#jn-62167) is a standard one for chewing e.g., meat.
- [ぐちゃぐちゃ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%90%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%90%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83/#jn-62168) can be used similarly. This is more rough, like wolves biting something drippy.
- [がつがつ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4/#jn-42536) sounds like biting something crispier (e.g., biting bones).

Cf.

- [擬音語・擬態語　ー　食べる、飲む](https://www.rondely.com/zakkaya/dic5/eat.htm)

Answer (score 8):

When chewing soft food loudly with mouth a bit open, I use くちゃくちゃ. It may become くっちゃくっちゃ or ぐちゃぐちゃ, depending on person and area. I guess, many Japanese people hate to hear the sound from such a way of eating, and this word may contain such attitude hating the chewing sound.

When chewing hard food (like rice cracker) and making sound, I use ぼりぼり. If the food is so much hard　(like ice cubes or fish bones), then I may choose がりがり or ばりばり.

If you want to express the attitute of eating, then もりもり gives positive and enthusiastics impression. For example, I chose it when kids are eating well for good health.

On the other hand, がつがつ gives negative impression and it may represent eating habit with bad manners. I also use it when eating with so much hunger, but I don't mean much negative sense in this case.

The choice of the words would differ depending on how you feel about the habit or the behaviour.

Comment: ガリガリ君めっちゃ好き!!!!

Comment: @istrasci is that some kind of quote or reference perhaps?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%AC%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AC%E3%83%AA%E5%90%9B&tbm=isch): sold in every convenience store in Japan since forever, hence known by anyone who has spent at least a summer or so in the country.

Comment: 私はチョコバリめっちゃ好き‼️